# All characters from collection combinations to create strings

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I have probably quite easy to solve problem. I have a 7 places in sequence of number and I have a 3 number (for example 0,1 and 2). I want to generate all possible string with length equals 7 containing this 3 numbers.
Something like this:
0000001
0000010
0000011
.
.
.
12020001
12021001
.
.
.
All possible combinations. How to implement this (for my purpose I'm going to do this in java)? I had statistics many years ago on my university and I didn't remember it ;) Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this solves your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create your list of numbers
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(0);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);

    getPermutations(list, 7, "");
}

/**
 * Prints all possible permutations with a given list of numbers and a given
 * length of the output strings.
 * 
 * @param list
 *            - The list of possible numbers
 * @param depth
 *            - The recursion depth which equals the lengths of the output
 *            strings
 * @param val
 *            - The current value of the output string
 */
public static void getPermutations(List<Integer> list, int depth, String val) {
    if (depth <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (depth == 1) {
        for (Integer number : list) {
            System.out.println(number + val);
        }
    } else {
        for (Integer number : list) {
            getPermutations(list, depth - 1, number + val);
        }
    }
}
```

It is more flexible because you can choose the lengths of the output strings and the list of possible numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Perl, but I expect something similar would work in Java:

```
for ($a1=0; $a1<=2; $a1++) {
  for ($a2=0; $a2<=2; $a2++) {
    for ($a3=0; $a3<=2; $a3++) {
      for ($a4=0; $a4<=2; $a4++) {
        for ($a5=0; $a5<=2; $a5++) {
          for ($a6=0; $a6<=2; $a6++) {
            for ($a7=0; $a7<=2; $a7++) {
              $O=$a1.$a2.$a3.$a4.$a5.$a6.$a7;
              print "$O\n";
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I suppose there are some better ways to do this, but for my purpose it's enough, thanks :)

Comment: @caro Please accept the answer to help other users who will visit that question.